# C++ - dynamic pointer of array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

first i would like to say i am Newbie in C++.

As part of my master thesis i am writing a program in C++ which also get as parameters the variables `m` and `d` (both integers). Were `d` is the power of 2 (this means `2^d` elements). Parameter `m` define the number of possible interactions between one element and the total group (`2^d` elements).

The number of possible interactions is computed as following:

```
\kappa = \sum_{i=0}^m\binom{d}{i}
```

(at present i generate vector of vectors for `2^d` x \kappa, but my Prof. would like me to create different statistics to different `m`'s. My first though was to to generate a dynamic array of `m` arrays of different sizes... Then i though of defining a 3-dim array with the biggest needed 2d array, but also program speed is important (e.g `d = 20`).

i would like to ask for your advice how to define such kind of dynamic array that will also be fast.

Regards

Comment: If array and maths speed is important to you, I have to ask why you are not using FORTRAN rather than C++?

Comment: Really?  I think blitz++ has proven that C++ can be competitive with FORTAN when it comes to high-performance number-crunching

Comment: Are you using native C++ vectors, or the vector<T> class from the standard libray?

Comment: before i started programming, i told my self that i don't know C++ or FORTRAN, so i chose for C++ out of the understanding that it would be more usefull in the future and maybe also easier to apply multi-thread computation.

Answer (score 0):

Use boost mutlidimensional arrays

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html

for example look at this code. This is very easy

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <cassert>

int main () {
  // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
  typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

  // Assign values to the elements
  int values = 0;
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
        A[i][j][k] = values++;

  // Verify values
  int verify = 0;
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
        assert(A[i][j][k] == verify++);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does Boost support jagged arrays? I think that is what Eagle wants.

Comment: I looked before in boost project and saw this code as well, but using boost multi-array type, you need to define the size at compilation time and i know the size of dimension only at run-time (executing). Assuming that in my case m = 3, but my two other dimension will not have the same size for all m's.

Comment: lets forget the discussion about accues speed, using a vector<vector<vector<double> > > will generate me a [m][n][p] array, which is bigger then what i need. I need for m = 0 an array of [n_0][p_0], for m = 1 i need an array of [n_1][p_1] and etc. were n_0 \neq n_1 and etc. I could also define n_max = max(n_0,n_1,...) and p_max = max(p_0,p_1,...) and generate [m}[n_max][p_max], but i am fear that such kind of code implementation would decrease speed preformence...

Comment: You can call .resize() for every single element in a vector<vector<double> >, and the same goes for vector<vector<vector<double> > >

Comment: Doc Brown, could you please write an example how you add an element to a vector<vector<double> >? it is also possible to use push_back(), which is also kind of resize.